# How can I recursively delete all empty files and directories in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I recursively cleanup all empty files and directories in a parent directory?

Let’s say I have this directory structure:

```
Parent/
  |____Child1/
        |______ file11.txt (empty)
        |______ Dir1/ (empty)

  |____Child2/
        |_______ file21.txt
        |_______ file22.txt (empty)

  |____ file1.txt
```

I should end up with this:

```
Parent/
  |____Child2/
        |_______ file21.txt

  |____ file1.txt
```

Comment: I wasn’t confused, *per se,* but, even before I saw the comments, I thought it was confusing that the illustration had multiple files with the same name.  You might want to consider using a naming convention like `Child1/file11.txt`, ``Child2/file21.txt`` and ``Child2/file22.txt``.

Comment: @Scott ok, I have updated the file names. I hope, now it will not confuse anymore.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is a really simple one liner:

```
find Parent -empty -delete
```

It's fairly self explanatory.  Although when I checked I was surprised that it successfully deletes Parent/Child1.  Usually you would expect it to process the parent before the child unless you specify `-depth`.

This works because `-delete` implies `-depth`.  See the [GNU find manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Delete-Files):

> `-delete` Delete files; true if removal succeeded. If the removal failed, an error message is issued. If -delete fails, find's exit status will be nonzero (when it eventually exits). Use of -delete automatically turns on the -depth option.

---

Note these features are not part of the [Posix Standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html), but most likely will be there under many Linux Distribution.  You may have a specific problem with smaller ones such as Alpine Linux as they are based on [Busybox](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) which doesn't support `-empty`.

Other systems that do include non-standard `-empty` and `-delete` include [BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) and [OSX](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html) but apparently not [AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/f_commands/find.html).

Comment: Please keep in mind that you are not quoting the `find` manual but the `gfind` manual. There would be no problem if you did describe a standard behavior of  `find`, but your answer depends on two non-standard features (`-empty` and `-delete`).

Comment: Incomprehensible what you mean "Parent"

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz The term "parent" is from the question. And very clear to most readers. It's also a very common term when working with tree structures such as directory trees.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a two command solution

#### Delete empty files

```
find Parent/ -type f -size 0 -delete
```

#### Try to remove *all* directories

```
find Parent/ -type d -depth -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir 2>/dev/null
```

*NB `rmdir` can't remove non-empty directories, thus it's safe to run but will produce errors, which we are hiding*

As above, but being a little more specific about the error messages being ignored.  Might need to amend if the message varies across distros.

```
find Parent/ -type d -depth -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir 2>&1 \
  | grep -iv "Directory not empty$"
```

Comment: Generally I wouldn't recommend trying to delete something and then discarding the error message.  It can hide errors for other unrelated reasons such as "access denied" errors.

Comment: That's fair, I'll add an alternative

Comment: Looks like GNU find has `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty`, funny enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with the `fd` tool:

```
fd -t e -x rm -r
```

https://github.com/sharkdp/fd