# Why does "find -delete" imply "-depth"?

Tags: find, rm, gnu

The man page for GNU `find` clearly warns that using `-delete` implies `-depth`. However, I cannot find any explanation for this requirement:

> **`-delete`** Delete  files; true  if removal succeeded. If the removal failed, an error message is issued. […] Use of `-delete` automatically turns on the `-depth` option.

```
find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0
```

This is implicitly a post-order walk:

```
find /path -type f -delete
```

But this is a pre-order walk, the usual method of traversal for `find`:

```
find /path -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

If I want to use `-prune` I cannot use `-delete` and instead I must use the more cumbersome `-exec rm {} +`, yet the net effect seems the same.

The `-delete` action does not remove directories, so why does `find -delete` need to imply `-depth`?

Comment: The `-depth` option is a bit unluckily named, `find` doesn't do a width-first (or breadth-first) walk even without it. Default `find` would walk `a`, `a/b`, `a/b/123` then `a/c`, while a proper breath-first search would walk the tree in the order `a`, `a/b`, `a/c`, then `a/b/123`, with the whole of the second level first, before descending to the third level. The `-depth` only changes if the inner nodes are processed before (preorder) or after (postorder) of their children, i.e. it turns the order to `a/b/123`, `a/b`, `a/c`, `a`, with the whole subtree of `a/b` still processed before `a/c`.

Comment: It's particularly useful when you want to delete empty files and directories https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577868/20140 because the directories may only become empty after deleting empty files.

Comment: @PhilipCouling if I want to do that there's `rm -rf`. If I want to select particular files and directories often I'll want to use `-prune`, and at that point `-delete` is useless to me anyway

Comment: @roaima look again, the `find . -empty -delete` will remove directories which become empty after discovering all existing files in them are empty, and leave alone directories with non-empty files. That's not simply achieved with just `rm -rf` because `-empty` would not see the directories as empty when they contain empty files.  I'll admit it would be no hassle to include `-depth` in the command though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The `-delete` action does not remove directories, so why does find `-delete` need to imply `-depth`?

For GNU utilities, the reference documentation is the utilities’ info files, not their man pages; as happens in some cases, the man page quoted in the question is misleading. [`find -delete` can remove directories](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Delete-Files.html):

> Delete files or directories; true if removal succeeded. If the removal failed, an error message is issued.

`-delete` has always supported deleting directories, ever since its introduction in GNU `find` in 2004 (`findutils` 4.2.3).

Deleting directories is the reason `-delete` implies `-depth`: it can only delete directories if it has previously emptied them. `-delete` on directories is equivalent to `rmdir`, not `rm -rf`.

The net effect of `find /path -type f -delete` and `find /path -type f -exec rm -f {} +` is the same because both `find` invocations limit their actions to files. Since only files are deleted, the order in which they are deleted has no effect on `find`’s traversal. When deleting directories, `find`’s traversal does come into play. If `-delete` is used on directories, then a directory’s children must all have been processed before the directory itself can be deleted; this is where `-depth` is useful. If `rm -rf` is used on directories being traversed, then `find` must be told about the deletion before it attempts to traverse a deleted directory’s children; this is one instance where `-prune` is useful.

One could imagine special-casing it so that it doesn’t set `-depth` if it’s not going to delete directories, but that’s impossible to determine ahead of time in the general case. (`-depth` is an option, not an action; it needs to be set before the first action is actually processed.)

Alternatively, [as has been proposed in the past](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-findutils/2007-08/msg00052.html), one could imagine not having any special handling of `-delete` at all, and letting the user take care of ensuring that `-delete` can do its job when it has to. However [this would break backwards compatibility](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-findutils/2007-08/msg00056.html) and compatibility with other implementations which have copied `-delete`. See also [the discussion in Savannah bug #20865](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?20865).

GNU `findutils` [explicitly checks for `-delete` combined with `-prune`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/parser.c?id=841aa66f1e447aa5db0b8800b121d0321dfa6ba2#n433) since version 4.3.11, and aborts if `-depth` hasn’t been explicitly set. The comments note that

> We only get away with this because the `-delete` predicate is not
> in POSIX.   If it was, we couldn't issue a fatal error here.

As discussed in [Why did find with -delete erase the files in my /save/ directory when find without delete was not able to locate them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256757/86440), if you’re using GNU `find`, you should use `-execdir rm {} +` instead of `-exec rm {} +`.

Comment: Thank you. Debian [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1003339) generated

Comment: @roaima I imagine the manpage says "files" in the sense of all types of files, including regular, directories, pipes, sockets, etc. Saying "files and directories" makes it sound like there's this grouping called "files" that include regular, pipes, sockets, etc. but not directories, or maybe it's more of a way of ignoring that there's more than just regular files and directories. No perfect terminology for documentation, I guess.